# Drupal on mouse over play sound

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I have a question about when mouse over a picture from a slider show, the sound (which is very short, just like a bing) will play. In normal case, I know how to use html, css and javascript to do it. I have a sound example here: https://freesound.org/people/Timbre/sounds/232210/
and let's say, the class in Drupal page.tpl.php is called picture. As I am new to Drupal, how should I make this function work by only using javascript or jquery? Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal you should add your scripts with `drupal_add_js()`. You can add either a file or inline js and set a number of options such as if it should appear on every page and if it should be added to the footer or header and if it requires jQuery.

You could create a js file with something like this inside:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var mySound = document.createElement('audio');
    mySound.setAttribute('src', '/path/to/my/sound.mp3');

    //play the sound when the visitor moves the mouse over
    //an element with the class 'picture'. 
    $('.picture').mouseover(function() {
        mySound.play();
    });
});
```

Then in your theme or module, you could use `hook_page_alter` to add your js:

```
drupal_add_js(
  '/path/to/js/script.js',
  array(
    'type' => 'file',
    'scope' => 'footer',
    'group' => JS_THEME, //or JS_DEFAULT if module
    'every_page' => false,
    'requires_jquery' => true,
  )
);
```

You could wrap that in some sort of if statement to only load it on the page(s) you need it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi! Many tks. that's really helpful!:-)